# Choose right Framework (Frontend, Backend) for high-performance, secure, scalable web application

Tags: java, spring, extjs, wicket, gwt-ext

i am planning to do a web application project with 2 backend developers and one designer/frontend developer.

The designer is a freelancer and works in a different office. that means for me fontend/backend development should be decoupled.

Other requirements:

- possibility to provide data interfaces to other application, that are easy to integrate
- system has to be very scalable and high-performant.
- amazing RIA User Interface with flexible reporting abilities
- ...

I thought about using a **Wicket/Spring** combination in the backend, **do you know how good theiy work together?**

For the frontend i wanted to use **Extjs** but i do not know **how it works together with wicket?** (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wicket-extjs/files/ this wicket-extjs project seams to be stopped in 2008)

I think **JQuery and HighCharts** for the charting would be a good combination here.

**which framworks would you use here and why?**

Comment: Wicket is a front-end library. Yes, it's templating generated by the server, and sent to the browser, but it's still front-end, and not server.

Answer (score 3):

I use wicket + spring together a lot, and it works fine.

I have also successfully integrated wicket with the following JS frameworks:

- JQuery
- MooTools
- Prototype / Scriptaculous
- YUI 3

Here is a Wiki entry on using JavaScript libraries: [Creating a behavior to use a Javascript library](http://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/creating-a-behavior-to-use-a-javascript-library.html)

Example: here's a behavior that changes a component's CSS classes using JQuery without actually replacing the component.

```
public class JQueryCssClassBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -493574907225091582L;

    @Override
    public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response){
        super.renderHead(response);
        response.renderJavascriptReference("path/to/jquery");
    }

    private final IModel<Collection<String>> classesModel;
    private final IModel<Boolean> toggleModel;

    public JQueryCssClassBehavior(final IModel<Collection<String>> classesModel,
        final IModel<Boolean> toggleModel){
        this.classesModel = classesModel;
        this.toggleModel = toggleModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void respond(final AjaxRequestTarget target){
        final Collection<String> classes = classesModel.getObject();
        if(classes != null && !classes.isEmpty()){
            final String classesAsString =
            // Use Joiner from Guava or any other technique
                Joiner.on(' ').join(classes);
            target.appendJavascript(
                "$('"
                + getComponent().getMarkupId()
                + "')."
                + (toggleModel.getObject().booleanValue()
                    ? "addClass"
                    : "removeClass") 
                + "('"
                + classesAsString
                + ");"
            );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanx for the real helpful answer. i think i am going to use wicket with spring. 

i have to try if i get extjs working with wicket. i think the single site concept of extjs could be a problem. letz see.

do you know some good training sources for spring and wicket? (weblogs, videos, tutorials ...)

Answer (score 1):

Wiquery and jWicket provide JQuery integration with Wicket. We use Wiquery a bit and it seems fine.